# MAMP Issues: Server not Found

Tags: localhost, mamp

I installed MAMP version 3.3 on my Macbook (OS X Yosemite v. 10.10.4) today.

I can start the servers; both Apache & MySQL servers appear to start with no issues; I have green lights on both.

However, when I hit "Open WebStart Page" I get a "Problem loading page" error. It says, "Firefox can't find the server at www.localhost.com."

With Apache port set to 8888 & MySQL port set to 8889, MAMP is looking for the server here: http://www.localhost.com:8888/MAMP/?language=English.

With Apache port set to 80 & MySQL port set to 8889, MAMP is looking for the server here: http://www.localhost.com/MAMP/?language=English.

With Apache port set to 80 & MySQL port set to 3306, MAMP is looking for the server here: http://www.localhost.com/MAMP/?language=English.

MAMP itself is looking for the WebStart page at the URLs I posted above. I get the same response at http://localhost, http://localhost:8888/MAMP, and http://localhost/MAMP.

Is this a problem with some setting in Firefox? When I type in URL http://localhost, it changes it to http://www.localhost.com/. Likewise, http://localhost:8888/MAMP becomes http://www.localhost.com:8888/MAMP/.

Answer (score 1):

First try it in a different browser and also try going to http://127.0.0.1:8888/. If that doesn't work, check your Proxy settings in firefox by doing the following:

1. Go to Options->Advanced->Network. In the "Connection" section press "Settings" to open the "Connection Settings".
2. The "No proxy for:" text field should contain the following text: "localhost, 127.0.0.1"

if it doesn't say that do this:

1. Select "Manual proxy configuration:"
2. Type "localhost, 127.0.0.1" in the "No proxy for:" text field

Comment: I am learning PHP through teamtreehouse.com. Their tutorial instructs us to change the Apache port to 80. Having done that, I directed my browsers to 127.0.0.1 and get a page that says, "Index of/". I assume that this is some sort of progress, but it is not the MAMP welcome page I am expecting. So how do I know if MAMP is actually working and usable?

Comment: Also, your instructions regarding the "No proxy for" and "Manual proxy configuration" do not prevent Firefox from directing a URL of http://localhost to http://www.localhost.com. Even after closing the browser application and restarting it.

Comment: I really appreciate your advice. It's obviously heading down the right path.

Comment: Okay, you are supposed to see the "Index of/" that means it is working. Is there a reason you need to see the welcome page? If not you are good to go. If you really want to see the welcome page you could try `http://127.0.0.1/MAMP/`